# Regex to find words starting with a colon

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm designing a text editor with vs 2013 express.I want to find words that starting
with a colon (:). Currently i use a regex for it.But it's not perfect.
This is my regex - ":\w+"
It finds words,but quite not the way i want.
My objective is to find words starting with a colon.(first character of the word is a colon ex- :Test )
But the words only at the start of a line.(not from the middle of a sentence)
And it should exclude words starting with two colons (::Test)
Hope you guys could help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^` anchor to match the start of a line.

```
^:(?!:)\S+
```

`:(?!:)` This negative lookahead asserts that the `:` would be followed by any but not of a `:`

OR

```
^:\w+
```

This matches the `:` and the following word characters only if it is at the start of a line.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fY6mZ6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Whether any colon come in between in the line.
or else you can use below code.

```
^:[^:]+
```

Try this too.